# Procedurally generating an endless terrain

Tags: c++, noise, procedural-generation

Right now I have a terrain in which the height of each vertex is generated with perlin noise. What I want to do is have this happen continually so as you move around more chunks can be loaded.

I have used procedural generation before but in that situation it did not matter what was in the sector before each sector would just have it's own values but in this situation where I am trying to generate a terrain, I cannot just generate another buffer with perlin noise and a different seed because the chunks of the terrain need to be consistant with eachother otherwise the terrain would look odd between each chunk.

How can I implement procedural generation and keep the terrain looking consistant?

Comment: Perlin noise is a mathematical function `f(x,y)`, or `f(x,y,z)` for the 3d case. You simply keep the seed, i.e. the same function, and input the appropriate `x,y` values for your new sector.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann The perlin noise function I am using takes in a buffer of seeds and another buffer which it fills with all the values it computes. If I were to use the same seeds I would get the same height map and the x and y value is just so the function knows the size of the buffer. Is there still a way I can do procedural generation like this?